# 'Marked by' vs 'having' in dictionary definitions

Tags: differences, expressions, dictionaries

I've read definitions that differ from each other only by the words *marked by* and *having*.

E.g. 'Marked by a calm demeanor' and 'having a calm demeanor'. I see this often enough that I suspect lexicographers distinguish between the two phrases.

For dictionary definitions, how do the denotations of *marked by* and *having* differ from each other?

Comment: This question should be asked in Writer's forum.

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in the *essence* of the definition. When defining a word using 'marked by', it means that the word describes some quality with a certain special characteristic, whereas using 'having' implies that the word principally describes such a special characteristic.

Thus in your example of 'a calm demeanor', the word whose definition contains 'marked by' could refer to a certain state of being with the hallmark of, that is, *marked by* a calm demeanor, whereas the word with 'having' in its definition would refer more specifically to the state *principally* characterized by *having* a calm demeanor.

Comment: You seem to have got carried away by the ideas -- the answer is as confusing as the OP's predicament.

Comment: @Kris it makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, I think @Samuel's answer is essentially that *is marked by* can mean *is distinguished by*.  That is, the quality is **sufficient** to distinguish it, rather than being just one of possibly several qualities that the object has. This can be relaxed somewhat as well: a square stem is a marker for, or distinguishes, plants of the mint family, even though not all mints have a square stem and not all square stems are from mints.

Comment: I  as a non-native speaker had a really hard time understanding this explanation but I think I finally got it. What did it for me was to realize that "that is" means "in other words" . Hope it'll help somebody who struggles with understanding.